# How to add a regular expression to validate a key of an object in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I would like to change my schema so that any property which start with `com.xxx.` will be invalid.

How do I achieve it? Where to localte the regular expression? Could you please provide me an example?

```
   {
        "com.xxx.myapp": "xxx"
    }


{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "The root schema",
    "description": "The root schema comprises the entire JSON document.",
    "default": {},
    "examples": [
        {
            "com.xxx.myapp": "xxx"
        }
    ],
    "required": [
        "com.xxx.myapp"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "com.xxx.myapp": {
            "$id": "#/properties/com.xxx.myapp",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The com.xxx.myapp schema",
            "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
                "xxx"
            ]
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `patternProperties` keyword. It's like `properties`, but the keys are non-anchored regular expressions.

> The value of "patternProperties" MUST be an object.  Each property
> name of this object SHOULD be a valid regular expression, according
> to the ECMA 262 regular expression dialect.  Each property value of
> this object MUST be a valid JSON Schema.
>
> This keyword determines how child instances validate for objects,
> and    does not directly validate the immediate instance itself.
> Validation    of the primitive instance type against this keyword
> always succeeds.
>
> Validation succeeds if, for each instance name that matches any
> regular expressions that appear as a property name in this keyword's
> value, the child instance for that name successfully validates
> against each schema that corresponds to a matching regular
> expression.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.5